# webdriverio does not load page in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am on ubuntu 14.04. This is my code:

```
var webdriverio = require('webdriverio');

var options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'firefox'
    }
}

webdriverio
    .remote(options)
    .init()
    .url('http://www.google.com')
    .title(function(err, res) {
        console.log(res.value)
    })
    .end();
```

When the browser window pops up nothing happens. No page is loaded and the url bar is blank.  There is no error either. Does anyone know what im doing wrong?

Comment: This looks very much like the lesson learnd here http://webdriver.io/guide.html do you stick to the steps described there?

Comment: Yes, that was the guide that i used. youll notice that my code is the same as theirs except that im using firefox. Chrome does not work because i dont have the chrome driver.

Comment: Sorry i cant follow - Their capabilities indicate firefox usage.

Comment: That's exactly what's puzzling to me. Maybe it has to do with the fact that I'm using Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a problem with firefox and the old selenium standalone version (42.2 I think). Please download the new version from [SeleniumHQ](http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/2.43/selenium-server-standalone-2.43.1.jar) site. That should work. Sorry someone already opened a PR for that and I merged but didn't deployed it yet.

Comment: For those who want to download Selenium HQ, please check the latest here - http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/